# Start another activity without click on any event from AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

There are many options for **launch an activity without click** on any events in Activity.But i didn't find any solution for launch an activity automatically without click any event on **AppWidgetProvider** ? Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what exactly the user will do with your app widget that should trigger an activity to start.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will get a result from webservice.So I will show the result on the widget.Then after 3 seconds I want to open an activity.

Comment: Why would the user want you to start an activity in the middle of whatever the user is doing?

Comment: @CommonsWare: As per the requirement I need to  do some actions/features on the activity.Please give me a solution

Comment: @CommonsWare : Have you got any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983302/how-to-show-the-text-selection-cursor-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will get a result from webservice

Presumably, your Web service request is being made from a service.

> So I will show the result on the widget.

Your service will do that by working with `AppWidgetManager`.

> Then after 3 seconds I want to open an activity.

Your service is welcome to wait three seconds, then call `startActivity()`. You will need to include `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the `Intent` that you pass to `startActivity()`.

Your users, in turn, are welcome to give your app poor reviews, etc. for interrupting them in the middle of whatever they are already doing with their device. Launching an activity from background work is rarely the right solution.

Note that nothing in what you are requesting has anything to do with `AppWidgetProvider`.